# How can i skew 2 upper corners of a div and keep a round corners?

Tags: css

I'm trying to create the following tabs style. I've tried many directions - but none seems to works...
I've tried to use clip-path - but it's removes the round borders.

```css
.wrapper {
display: flex;
}

.tab {
width:100px;
padding: 5px;
background-color: tomato;
text-align:center;
margin-right:5px;
border-top-left-radius:10px;
border-top-right-radius:10px;
//clip-path: polygon(10% 0%,90% 0%,100% 100%,0% 100%);
//transform-origin: 100% 50%;
//transform: perspective(100px);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="tab">
1
</div>
<div class="tab">
2
</div>
<div class="tab">
3
</div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: May be you can get some help from here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qzMy7yC9QvM

Comment: this might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63280902/8620333