# How can I mask a div with a background image?

Tags: html, css, svg, css-shapes, clip-path

I am looking to build a container to put some content in. I want to have a little text for the "notch" or the "tab" in the top.

I tried building the same thing with pseudo elements but found it to be very difficult because of the image that I want to mask. Another problem I found with pseudo-elements and specifically is that its hard to achieve if your background is anything else than a solid color.

This is the code I used to achieve the effect. I am wondering if there is a better responsive way of building this? What if I want the notch to be responsive to the size of the text I want to put there?

```css
body {
  background: #F7EAE2;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  font-family: montserrat;
}

.masking {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 700px;
  height: 400px;
  background: url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885_1280.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  clip-path: url(#mask);
  mask-size: 100%;
}

p {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="masking">
    <p>Is there a better way?</p>
  </div>
  
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="0" height="0">
    <defs>
      <clipPath id="mask" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
        <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M0,0.098 C0,0.086,0.005,0.077,0.012,0.077 H0.068 C0.075,0.077,0.081,0.068,0.081,0.057 V0.021 C0.081,0.009,0.086,0,0.093,0 H0.223 C0.23,0,0.235,0.009,0.235,0.021 V0.057 C0.235,0.068,0.241,0.077,0.247,0.077 H0.988 C0.995,0.077,1,0.086,1,0.098 V0.979 C1,0.991,0.995,1,0.988,1 H0.012 C0.005,1,0,0.991,0,0.979 V0.098"/>
      </clipPath>
    </defs>
  </svg>
</body>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62591336/8620333

Comment: Thank you so much for that!!!

It made me understand it much more. 

I made a little fun project out of it as I was playing with my new knowledge :)

https://codepen.io/Christoffer-Forst-n/pen/BaMZjKj